# How would you indicate a single direction trip?

Tags: compounds

This question came up today in the office. We sell single direction bus trips through our site (wanderu.com) but have not agreed on which English word(s) should be used in text.

Is it one-way or one way? Does one or the other communicate that "way" is a noun (e.g. direction) as opposed to a verb (e.g. method to an end)?

We consulted the Wikipedia disambiguation page, [One-way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way), which links to pages like [One-way traffic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_traffic). This English for these pages would suggest "one-way" is the appropriate word. The images on the traffic page, however, has two words.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In Britain a one-way ticket, by bus or rail, is usually called a *single*, as opposed to a *return*. It can be expressed as *single ticket* or *return ticket*.

Comment: Dictionary: A book or electronic resource that lists the words of a language (typically in alphabetical order) and gives their meaning, or gives the equivalent words in a different language, often also providing information about pronunciation, origin, and usage:: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/one-way

Comment: The trip is a "one-way" trip, meaning that it is "one way".  You insert the hyphen when the phrase is used as an adjective on another word ("trip").  But whether or not you use the hyphen, there's little risk that "way" will be interpreted to mean "method to an end", when the context is clearly travel.

Comment: Um ... delete the wikipedia bookmark on your browser.

Comment: Snarky comments and useful answers. I think I like this place. Thanks all.

Comment: WS2 -- like me, you didn't notice the OP is asking about the damned hyphen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct expression for a ticket is *[one-way](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/one-way)*:

> (Of a ticket) allowing a person to travel to a place but not back
> again; single.

The confusion is that on the sign it is not referring to one-way traffic, but rather to the one way that you are permitted to travel on the street: one direction.

[image]

In reference to the ticket, *one-way* is the adjective modifying the noun *ticket*. In reference to the sign, *one* is the adjective modifying the noun, *way*.

Comment: The question was *one-way* ticket as opposed to *one way* on the sign, and the answer accepts that limited frame of reference. *One way ticket* is not the correct expression; *one-way* ticket is. In Germany it is Einbahn.

Comment: I agree with Joe, English is certainly not universal even within a single country. But this does express the differences in a way I could not gather. Thanks very much!

Comment: Sprry Scott I didn't even notice the OP was asking about the hyphen